# Host how can we execute according to the cloudlets arrival time when there are multiple VMs

Tags: java, cloud, cloudsim

If we have 50 cloudlets,10 VMs  and one Host how can we execute them according to the cloudlets arrival time, not to the VM orders in the host. note that I using cloudsim simulator

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you've tried already?

Comment: I tried to update CloudSimExample1 code in clouddim, I create 50 cloudlets 
In each loop I assign it to random VM, then I sent them to the broker. 
In the broker I resorted cloudlets based on cloudlets arrival time
But when I run the simulator the result are executed according to vm order
Note that I using CloudletSchedulerSpaceShared for the VMs

Answer (score -1):

Cloudlets are scheduled on the base of arrival, not on the base of VMs. 1st cloudlet is bound to the first VM and second to 2nd VM and so on. If you want to bound cloudlet to specific VM use broker.bindCloudletToVm(cloudlet id, vm id) function.