# how can we schedule cloudlets Round-Robin scheduling algorithm if the quantum time=5

Tags: scheduled-tasks, computer-science, round-robin, cloudsim

how can we schedule cloudlets using Round-Robin scheduling algorithm  if they are sorted according to the arrival time.

For example there are 2 VMs and 6 cloudlets. Cloudlets exec time= 12, 5, 10, 7, 15, 18 Quantum = 5 Can you guide me in an example? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

CloudSim doesn't provide a CloudletScheduler that consider quantum time (time slices).
There is an answer for a similar question that explains exactly what you are looking for. Check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779655/how-the-timeshared-in-cloudsim-work-in-cloudsim). It uses [CloudSim Plus](http://cloudsimplus.org), a modern version of CloudSim that provides lots of exclusive features.